# Как поменять местами два слова из трех в ячейке

Tags: excel

Есть у меня ячейка в эксел, данные туда получаю из базы.
Есть текст `Концентрация оксида азота`, нужно чтобы было вот так

```
Концентрация азота оксида
```

Делаю такой скрипт но получается не то.

```
=ПСТР(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)+1;300)&" "&ПСТР(N31;1;ПОИСК(" ";N31))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое слово:

```
=ЛЕВБ(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)-1)
```

Второе слово:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(N31;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));99;99))
```

Третье слово:

```
=ПСТР(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)+1)+1;99)
```

Осталось все это объединить в требуемом порядке:

```
=ЛЕВБ(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)-1)&" "&ПСТР(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)+1)+1;99)&" "&СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(N31;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));99;99))
```

С разбивкой по словам понятнее и при необходимости можно самостоятельно переставлять слова.

Формула может быть проще, но менее понятна :)

Например:

```
=ЛЕВБ(ЗАМЕНИТЬ(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31);;ПСТР(N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31;ПОИСК(" ";N31)+1);99));ДЛСТР(N31))
```

Здесь последнее слово вставляется между первым и вторым и строка обрезается по длине исходного текста (для удаления последнего слова)

Comment: Спасибо работает